# SQL Server 2014 - Stored Procedure to perform conditional checks on a table

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2014, multiple-conditions

I'm new to SQL and I have imported several `.csv` files that I have joined in SQL Server. I will be using SSIS packages to automate these imports.

I wanted to create a stored procedure to perform a series of checks on one of these tables and populate a column that I have listed as a flag.

The check performs a comparison of two columns already within the database table.

One check is a condition where I would like to compare two price columns to see if the variance between the two is greater than 50%. If so, then I'd like to populate my flag column with a 1, if not, then 0.

I'm not really sure where to start. Any suggestions or examples that you may have would really help me out. Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you start simple and search for some tutorials on how to write `INNER JOIN`s and some tutorials on `CASE WHEN` expressions.

Comment: Please provide additional Info: WHat is the structure of your table? Can you provide some example on which data is already in the table and which column has to be modified in dependency from which other columns? In Other words: Provide an example of your data and additionally an example on what you expect as a result after the execution of the procedure.